# Generate thumbnail for video on external site

Tags: python, django, video-streaming

I have a lot of external links from users, and I need to scrap somehow the video content and generate thumbnail for it to display on my site.

I know this is a simple task with [django-oembed](http://code.google.com/p/django-oembed/), but the list of providers is limited. I need to support sites without oembed too.

So the main task is to determine if page contains the video or no, and generate thumbnail for it.

Can anybody suggest the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pymedia](http://pymedia.org/) to extract a frame from the video and [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to create the thumbnail like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772599/creating-thumbnails-from-video-files-with-python)

Comment: generation of thumbnails isn't the problem. Main task is to determine if page contains the video  and show thumbnail for remote video on my site