# Making screengrabs from a video file in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer

I'm thinking of making a thumbnail creator for video files.

It would grab frames from the video and arrange them to make a single image of the screens combined together.

Which librairies should I use to extract the frames and combine them ?

Is gstreamer my best option for the first part ?

What should I use to combine them ? PIL (python imaging library) isn't ported to python 3 yet, is there an alternative ?

Comment: Maybe these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772599/creating-thumbnails-from-video-files-with-python  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789652/how-to-create-video-thumbnails-with-python-and-gstreamer

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have seen both of these threads but I am still looking for more information on the topic.